# JDBC connection to MS SQL Server 2019 database

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, java-7

We currently use Webcenter Sites and we connect to a MS SQL 2014 DB. We are planning to upgrade to SQL Server 2019. Although I don't know of any issues we use Java 7 due to the age of the WCS applications in use and Spring Framework. Can we use normal Java 7 JDBC connection to the database over port 1433?

Some sites suggested that SQL Server 2019 will not support a connection made by Java 7 JDBC, but as the JDBC connection is flat I cannot see this being an issue, but any guidance would be welcome.

Comment: seems too broad a question and/or better placed on SuperUser or ServerFault.

Comment: Hey @Gary, Good question, but not for this server. Here you are expected to be very specific about a very concrete problem and even show some of own research, before posting a question.
Please try to ask similar Q that invoke discussion instead here: 
https://stackexchange.com/

Comment: @SoldOut Stack Exchange does not take questions; only its subsites do. So one would have to choose a subsite. But it might be that vague questions of 'will something go wrong', without the user just testing for themselves, will also be considered off-topic at those sites.